# Recursive ignoring and not-ignoring with tortoise-svn and with command line svn

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svnignore

I have a repository with these folders, and where I have these goals:

```
/temp/           <-- I want svn to ignore this
/**/temp         <-- I want svn to ignore this ('temp' in any recursive folder, i.e. at any depth level)
/bar/**/temp     <-- I want svn to NOT ignore 'temp' anywhere inside 'bar' (at any depth level)
```

Reading svn:ignore docs, I can't find any syntax that could deal with this problem.

a) Is this doable using tortoise-svn client?

b) What about regular command line svn client?

Answer (score 1):

Your question contains two parts, 1) how to recursively ignore directories and 2) how to not-ignore a certain directory.

The first issue cannot be solved using Subversion's `svn:ignore` property as this is evaluated on a per-directory level. Since Subversion v1.8, a `svn:global-ignores` property is supported which is applied to all subdirectories of a working copy (thanks to user [bahrep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/761095/bahrep) for pointing it out). Documentation can be found in the [Red Bean Book chapter on Ignoring Unversioned Items](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html).

At the root of your working copy, you can

```
svn propset svn:global-ignores temp .
```

or set the property using TortoiseSVN.

The answer to your second issue is already hidden in the linked page's title: you only ignore *unversioned* items. Once you've `svn add`'ed a file or a directory, it will no longer be ignored. Even if `global-ignores` or `svn:ignore` would say otherwise.

By the way, the evaluation of `svn:ignore` is the same no matter if you're using TortoiseSVN or `svn` CLI. The interface is different, the underlying functionality is the same.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm looking for a solution that involves zero manual work (no matter what dirs may be added in the future), and ideally no scripting/cmdline (this is intended to be a solution for non-technical people in varied environments where different script interpreters may or may not be available).
So it appears the only option would be to have a commit hook running on server side? Which would automatically apply appropriate svn:ignore strings (computed from a more powerful ignore syntax I would need to invent, being careful not to overwrite the user-written part of ignore string).

Comment: @STenyaK I guess you could set the `svn:ignore` property on a newly added directory as part of a commit hook. Keep in mind it will only be propagated to the users once they `svn update` their working copies. I don't know what powerful syntax you want to invent, I don't see the necessity. FWIW, `svn:ignore` is a client feature that prevents their output being cluttered by build artifacts. If you absolutely want to *prevent* certain files from being added, you need to write a commit hook anyway.

Comment: And what about global ignores? Those in the runtime config file and the corresponding property.

Comment: @bahrep that should solve OP's problem. Thank you for your comment. I edited my answer accordingly. Since you found it, I'd also happily upvote an answer of yours.

Comment: @STenyaK I updated my answer using bahrep's excellent suggestion. I believe this should solve your problem. Kindly take a look.